# MySQL Triggers: Inserting a variable

Tags: mysql, triggers

The following adds a country code to each new row inserted, in this case "US" for "United States".

```
CREATE TRIGGER `country` BEFORE INSERT ON `test`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`countryCode` = CASE 
WHEN NEW.`country` LIKE 'United States' THEN 'US'
END
```

The above works well, but I also want to insert a variable. The code below generates a #1064 syntax error:

```
SET @countryCode = 'US'
CREATE TRIGGER `country` BEFORE INSERT ON `test`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.`countryCode` = CASE 
WHEN NEW.`country` LIKE 'United States' THEN @countryCode
END
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to use a variable so that multiple country codes can be concatenated and inserted in the same column.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable inside the trigger.
Try:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `country` BEFORE INSERT ON `test`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
 SET @countryCode = 'US';
 SET NEW.`countryCode` = 
        CASE WHEN NEW.`country` LIKE 'United States' 
           THEN @countryCode end;
END; //
delimiter ;
```

Comment: Thanks, but same error code. Could PHPMyAdmin be to blame?

Comment: Ooh yeah, if you are using PHPMyAdmin, try removing the `delimiter` commands also the double slack after `end`

Comment: And I just realized the case command was missing an `end` as well!

Comment: This is all you need to insert into PHPMyAdmin: SET NEW.`countryCode` = CASE 
WHEN NEW.`country` LIKE 'United States' THEN 'US'
END

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `country` BEFORE INSERT ON `test`
FOR EACH ROW IF (NEW.tagline LIKE '%United States%') THEN
SET @countryCode = "US";
SET NEW.`taglineCode` = @countryCode;
END IF
```